# Rtexttools Trouble creating document term matrix with create_matrix

Tags: r, supervised-learning

I'm using RTextTools for the first time. Here's my code for create_matrix

```
library(RTextTools)
texts <- c("This is the first document.", 
          "Is this a text?", 
        "This is the second file.", 
        "This is the third text.", 
        "File is not this.") 
doc_matrix <- create_matrix(texts, language="english", removeNumbers=FALSE, stemWords=TRUE, removeSparseTerms=.2)
```

I'm getting the following error(s):

```
Error in `[.simple_triplet_matrix`(matrix, , sort(colnames(matrix))) : 
Invalid subscript type: NULL.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
2: In is.na(j) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
```

I haven't seen anyone else post this error yet, and figure there's something very basic which I am missing.

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the final argument, `removeSparseTerms=.2)`  From the `tm` package documentation on `removeSparseTerms`: "A term-document matrix where those terms from x are removed which have at least a sparse percentage of empty (i.e., terms occurring 0 times in a document) elements. I.e., the resulting matrix contains only terms with a sparse factor of less than sparse."

I think the sparseness threshold is too low for your data set.

Answer (score -1):

```
doc_matrix <- create_matrix(texts, language="english", removeNumbers=FALSE, stemWords=TRUE, removeSparseTerms=.9999)
```